# Bash script to start java maven project

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a problem. I am new with bash scripts, but I am trying to make a startup script for my java maven project. When I want to start the program I run the following command in a terminal:
`cd /var/script/myproject/java && mvn exec:java`

Now I am trying to translate this to bash, but I can't get it to work. First I tried the following line:

```
exec cd /var/script/myproject/java && mvn exec:java
```

But this resulted in the error:

```
/var/script/myproject/java_toggle.sh: line 6: exec: cd: not found
```

Then I saw this site: https://www.baeldung.com/linux/cd-command-bash-script
where I saw that they used the `cd` command seperatly, so I tried the following:

```
cd /var/script/myproject/java 
exec mvn exec:java
```

But this doesn't seem to change the directory of the exec, because it said that there was no maven project. How can I run `mvn exec:java` in a different directory as the bash script? Please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**cd** is internal bash command, and "exec" trying to execute it by itself instead of bash, but there is no /bin/cd (and there is no sense in such tool)

So possibly you need to

```
exec "/bin/bash -c 'cd /var/script/myproject/java && mvn exec:java'"
```

Comment: It says: `line 5: /root/bash -c 'cd /var/script/myproject/java && mvn exec:java': No such file or directory`.... But it does work when I run the command in the terminal. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: what is /root/bash ? It should be /bin/bash
Try to run 
exec "/bin/bash -c 'cd /var/script/myproject/java && mvn exec:java'"